# How to prove that the mapping $f\longmapsto f'$ from $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $D:H^1(\mathbb{R})\to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be the operator given by $D(f)=Df$ where $Df\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is the weak derivative of $f$, that is, the function $Df$ satisfies $$\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)\varphi'(x)dx=-\int_\mathbb{R}Df(x)\varphi(x)dx$$ for all $\varphi\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$. I think this operator is closed, then I'm trying to prove it and need help.

Let $(h_n)$ be a sequence in $H^1(\mathbb{R})$. Suppose there exists $h,g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\|h_n-h\|_{L^2}\to 0$ and $\|Dh_n-g\|_{L^2}\to 0$. In order to prove that $D$ is [closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator#Closed_linear_operators) we need to show that $h\in H^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $Dh=g$. In other words, we need conclude

$$\int_\mathbb{R}h(x)\varphi'(x)dx=-\int_\mathbb{R}g(x)\varphi(x)dx\tag{1}$$ for all $\varphi\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$.

Notice that

$$\int_\mathbb{R}|h(x)\varphi'(x)+g(x)\varphi(x)|dx\leq 0\Rightarrow\left|\int_\mathbb{R}h(x)\varphi'(x)+g(x)\varphi(x)dx\right|=0\Rightarrow(1).\tag{2}$$

Therefore it's enough to show that the inequality in $(2)$ holds. Since

$$\begin{align*}
  |h(x)\varphi'(x)+g(x)\varphi(x)|&\leq|h(x)-h_n(x)||\varphi'(x)| +|h_n(x)\varphi'(x)+Dh_n(x)\varphi(x)|+ \\
&+|g(x)-Dh_n(x)||\varphi(x)|,
\end{align*}$$
we can write

$$\int_\mathbb{R}|h(x)\varphi'(x)+g(x)\varphi(x)|\leq\int_\mathbb{R}|h(x)-h_n(x)||\varphi'(x)|dx +\\+\int_\mathbb{R}|h_n(x)\varphi'(x)+Dh_n(x)\varphi(x)|dx
+\int_\mathbb{R}|g(x)-Dh_n(x)||\varphi(x)|dx.\tag{3}$$

It seems that (by Hölder's inequality) we can conclude that the first and the last integral in the left-hand side of $(3)$ goes to zero, but I don't if this conclusion is true for the second one. Is it a good approach? How can we finish it?

Thanks.

Comment: What norm have you on $H^1(\mathbb{R})$? With $\lVert f\rVert_{H^1} = \left(\lVert f\rVert_{L^2}^2 + \lVert f'\rVert_{L^2}^2\right)^{1/2}$ it is immediate that $D$ is continuous.

Comment: @DanielFischer The norm is that you wrote. The continuity at zero (and hence in the domain, by linearity) is immediate because $$\|f\|_{H^1}<\varepsilon\Rightarrow\|Df\|_{L^2}^2\leq\|f\|_{L^2}^2+\|Df\|_{L^2}^2=\|f\|_{H^1}^2<\varepsilon^2\Rightarrow\|Df\|_{L^2}<\varepsilon.$$
Right?

Since $D$ continuous, it's bounded. So, $D$ is closed (by lemma 4.13-5 [in this book](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=nZmpQgAACAAJ&dq=editions:o6E9qYL1N4YC&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=ajXDUuv0E4i6kQeD_IDwBw&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA)) because its domain $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ is closed (with respect $\|\cdot\|_{L^2}$). Is it correct?

Comment: $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ is not closed in $L^2$. It is dense, in fact. Looking at the densely defined unbounded operator on $L^2$, we have to make a small extra step.

Comment: @DanielFischer In your first comment you said that $D$ is continuous and, in the last one, you said that $D$ is unbounded. How is it possible a continuous linear operator be unbounded?

Comment: $D$ is continuous as an operator $H^1(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R})$, if we endow both with their natural topologies. It is not continuous if we endow $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ with the subspace topology induced by the inclusion $H^1(\mathbb{R}) \hookrightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$. I didn't realise at first that you were looking at the latter, not the former.

Comment: @DanielFischer Are the "natural topologies" of $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ the topologies induced by the metrics induced by the norms $\|\cdot\|_{H^1}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{L^2}$, respectively?

Comment: Yes. These are the topologies the spaces have been defined for. Although it might be worth mentioning that I didn't use "natural" in a technical sense there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at the graph of $D$,

$$\Gamma(D) = \left\lbrace (f, Df) : f \in H^1(\mathbb{R})\right\rbrace \subset L^2(\mathbb{R}) \times L^2(\mathbb{R}),$$

we see that $\iota \colon H^1(\mathbb{R}) \to \Gamma(D);\; \iota(f) = (f, f')$ is a bijection that is isometric with respect to the canonical norm on $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ and the Hilbert-product norm on $L^2(\mathbb{R})\times L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Thus $\Gamma(D)$ is a complete subspace of $L^2(\mathbb{R})\times L^2(\mathbb{R})$, hence closed. Thus $D$ is a closed operator.

We could also continue the way you have started, if $h_n \xrightarrow{L^2} h$ and $Dh_n \xrightarrow{L^2} g$, then $(h_n)$ and $(Dh_n)$ are both Cauchy sequences in $L^2$, and that means $(h_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $H^1$. Since $H^1$ is complete, there is a $h^\ast \in H^1$ with $h_n \xrightarrow{H^1} h^\ast$. But that means nothing but

- $h_n \xrightarrow{L^2} h^\ast$, and
- $Dh_n \xrightarrow{L^2} Dh^\ast$.

Which implies $h = h^\ast$ and $g = Dh^\ast$, so $(h,g) \in \Gamma(D)$.